# Cannot view sauce labs test results

Tags: node.js, appium, saucelabs

I have two questions here. One, I am not able to run my appium tests against the sauce labs driver url specified in my account settings https://xxxxx:xxxxxxx@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub. I do not get any error too..

But, i am able to run my tests against http://appium.testobject.com/wd/hub url. But i am not sure where to see my test results. If i try https://app.testobject.com, I am not able to login even though i give the correct credentials and am already logged in sauce labs. Please help.

Comment: This question is better suited for the support of Sauce Labs, or maybe even contact your Customer Success Manager at Sauce Labs on how to use

Comment: hi @wswebcreation thanks for the suggestion. But i am in the trial period checking out the usage. Am not sure if i can contact customer support manager. But I will check into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to view my test results while using http://appium.testobject.com/wd/hub url. Navigate to saucelabs as usual. Then select "legacy rdc" under Sauce Apps in the displayed page. You can view the results in the displayed window.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few things that could be doing wrong here. First, you are trying to run the tests on the European datacenter and port 443, which is an https connection. [See which endpoint you should connect to](https://docs.saucelabs.com/basics/data-center-endpoints/). Some possible solutions:

1. Make sure you are using the endpoint for US West (if you are in the US and that is the data center you signed up for)
2. All your capabilities are up to date
3. You used your sauce username and access key when connecting to the driver.

It's hard to know what is wrong without capabilities and knowing if you want to connect to a virtual device or a real device, testing an app or browser. Here is an example configuration for an app test on RDC:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup(Method method) throws MalformedURLException {

    System.out.println("Sauce iOS Native - BeforeMethod hook");
    String username = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME");
    String accesskey = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");
    String sauceUrl;
    if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("eu")) {
        sauceUrl = "@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443";
    } else {
        sauceUrl = "@ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com:443";
    }
    
    String SAUCE_REMOTE_URL = "https://" + username + ":" + accesskey + sauceUrl +"/wd/hub";
    String appName = "iOS.RealDevice.SauceLabs.Mobile.Sample.app.2.7.1.ipa";
    String methodName = method.getName();
    URL url = new URL(SAUCE_REMOTE_URL);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 8.*");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCuiTest");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "storage:filename="+appName);
    try {
        iosDriver.set(new IOSDriver(url, capabilities));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("*** Problem to create the iOS driver " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```